# HTML User Input Type Restriction

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Restriction:

Can't type negative numbers, Decimal Numbers, Numbers < 2 and Numbers > 99

So far I have:

```
<input required type="number" min="2" max="99" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" maxLength="2" matInput value="{{element[col]}}" [(ngModel)]="element[col]">
```

It restricts the user from typing negative numbers only.

I can validate with function but I need to restrict the typing.

Kindly, share a few thoughts as I'm programming front-end for the very first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution you're looking for is this:

```
<input required type="number" min="2" max="99" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" maxLength="2" matInput value="{{element[col]}}" [(ngModel)]="element[col]">
```

But I guess it will lose the previous input. For that, you'll need to maintain a state variable in your component and restore the earlier value.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout below code;

HTML part:

```
 <input required id="id2" type="number" min="2" max="99" oninput="someFunction(this)">
```

Javascript part:

```
 let b = "";

function someFunction(a) {
    if (inpObj.checkValidity()) {
        a.value = a.value;
        b = a.value
    } else if (!a.value) {
        a.value = ""
    } else {
        a.value = b;
    }
}
```

You can modify this according to your need.